# Deliberately delayed response from JBoss

Tags: jboss

What is the best way to deliberately delay a response from the JBoss server?

I would like to implement a delayed login functionality, where if a username has been used in a failed login attempt recently, the AS will wait a few seconds before returning to the user. The stack consists of SQL-db, JBoss runnning the application, EJBs exposed to SOAP webservice adapters which in turn will be used by the clients.

Obviously Thread.sleep() won't do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not seem possible, nor reasonable to delay the responses from the application server.

This is a feature that should be implemented on the client side.